# Need suggestion in creating android string matching patterns to validate my text fields

Tags: android, string, pattern-matching, textedit

I have 4 text fields in my android app. Those are Name, email, phone number and password.
I want to validate the input fields after user enters the details in text fields.

Can anybody help me in writing the string matching patterns (compiled regular expressions) for these 4 text fields. The criteria is as follows

1. Name field should contain FirstName and LastName separated with white space.
2. Email : as simple like normal should contain sometext@sometext.sometext
3. Phone number : should check for numbers with length 12 numbers
4. password : should contain only alphanumeric characters and should be of length min 6 and max 8.

Please help me in this. I am stuck with my project for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) site, they have tons of known regular expressions listed. Also [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/), and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)